# htaccess redirect year in url from 2 digits to 4

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've many url that's end with a date with. I need 301 redirect to a 4 digits year.
Example:

redirect `www.example.com/report.php?date=27-02-16`
to `www.example.com/report/date-27-02-2016`

I've done this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/report\.php$<br>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^date=([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+) [NC]<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/report/date-%1? [R=301,L]
```

That works fine but i need absolutely 4 year digits.

The good news is that the year is always after 2000, so just add a 20 before the last 2 digits.
Someone has an idea to help me solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /report\.php\?date=([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /report/date-%1-%2-20%3? [L,R]
```